# Sub-setting variable column in melt data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, linechart

```
Data :

Cat <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)

variable <- c("IL_1_Flag_p", "IL_1_Flag_p", "IL_1_Flag_p", "IL_1_Flag_p", "IL_2_Flag_p", "IL_2_Flag_p", "IL_2_Flag_p","IL_2_Flag_p", "IL_3_Flag_p", "IL_3_Flag_p", "IL_3_Flag_p", "IL_3_Flag_p", "IL_4_Flag_p", "IL_4_Flag_p", "IL_4_Flag_p", "IL_4_Flag_p", "IL_5_Flag_p", "IL_5_Flag_p", "IL_5_Flag_p", "IL_5_Flag_p")

value <- c(21,17,16,210,20,17,15,189,20,17,15,188,19,17,15,188,20,17,15,194)

agg_melt_p <- data.frame(cat, variable, value)
```

I want to plot line chart for only "IL5_Flag_p" which is in the variable column.Tried using `subset` from `plyr` package but it is not working and showing error . I am combining 2 plots (a bar chart and this line chart).Original data uses melted dataframe from `melt` in `reshape2`

For ggplot I am using this piece:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(data = agg_melt_p, aes(x=Category , y=value , colour=variable))
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution using `dplyr`:

```
agg_melt_p %>% filter(variable == "IL_5_Flag_p") %>%
ggplot() + 
geom_line(aes(x=Cat, y=value, colour = variable))
```

This subsets the data frame the way you want without altering the object itself and then passes it to your ggplot command. The `colour=variable` bit in your code is not necessary, but you can leave it in if you want to generate a legend automatically.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @tifu . This works perfectly . Will keep this command in my arsenal .